# "< waiting for any device >" message, when I try to unlock bootloader on Moto g(9) plus

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, bootloader-lock, motorola

I want to unlock the bootloader on my Motorola Moto G9 Plus to install TWRP recovery, so I setup ADB and Fastboot on my PC, Enable USB debugging and OEM Unlock on my phone, connected it to my PC, opened the command prompt, wrote `adb reboot bootloader` command, and it was completed successfully. But when I wrote `fastboot flashing unlock`, I got this message:

```
C:\Windows\system32> cd C:\Platform-tools\platform-tools

C:\Platform-tools\platform-tools>adb reboot bootloader
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

C:\Platform-tools\platform-tools>fastboot flashing unlock
< waiting for any device >
```

<sup>[Original screenshot of the terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfOdQ.png)</sup>

My phone is displayed in the device manager like this:

> - Universal Serial Bus devices
>
>   - moto g(9) plus

<sup>[Original screenshot of Windows Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPG8N.png)</sup>

What should I do to unlock the bootloader now?

Comment: Do you have your unique key? You need to use "fastboot oem unlock {uniquekey}" to unlock most Motorola devices. https://en-us.support.motorola.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87215

Comment: Hello, acejavelin! Thank you for your comment, I'll try it!=)

Comment: regardless of that, the message is unrelated to bootloader unlocking, you simply have no connection.

Comment: In device manager select the moto g9 entry and then switch view to "Device by Connection" to what other devices are detected by Windows and which drivers whey are assigned to.